# Recyclerview not populated, Blank screen

Tags: java, android

Please help me with this, I have created a simple `recyclerview` but i'm not getting output on the screen, it is blank
This is my adapter class, I have been trying to debug this the whole day with no success, Also the there is no error while executing

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    public ContactAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public ContactAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.contact,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.email.setText(contact.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name,email;
        ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            name= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            email=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        }
    }
    }
```

This is my mainactivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ContactAdapter adapter;
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adapter=new ContactAdapter(this);
Contact c1=new Contact("potato","xyz@gmail.com");

adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
contacts.add(c1);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: you are adding data after setting the adapter try to up set adapter after data is added completely or call notifiyDataSetChanged() after adding contacts i.e after contacts.add(c1);

Comment: after the line contacts.add(c1) i have added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but still no result

Answer (score 1):

you are adapter

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    public ContactAdapter(Activity context,List<Contact> _list)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.contacts=_list;
        mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setDataChange(List<Contact> asList) {
        this.contacts = asList;
        //now, tell the adapter about the update
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.contact,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.email.setText(contact.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name,email;
        ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            name= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            email=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        }
    }
    }
```

your `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
 ContactAdapter adapter;
 List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Contact c1=new Contact("potato","xyz@gmail.com");
    contacts.add(c1);
    adapter=new ContactAdapter(this,contacts);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Adapter` you have to create that add method:

```
public void add(Contact c1) {
    chatModelList.add(c1);
    notifyItemInserted(contacts.size() - 1);
}
```

Another way:

```
List<Contact> result = getResult();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, result);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

private List<Contact> getResult() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    contactList.add(new Contact("A","B"));
    return contactList;
}
```

Now in your adapter class:

```
private Context context;
private List<Contact> contact = new ArrayList<>();


public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contact) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contact = contact;
}
```

Comment: I'm adding Contact Object to the List as List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>(); and then after creation of Contact object i add it to the list contacts.add(c1);

Comment: It works now, Thank you so much. Now I know why it was not working. You're a life saver.

Comment: Your other way of doing is much cleaner. I'll follow your style in the future

Comment: But i'm unable to upvote bcz I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: Glad to know it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of contacts in your main, but you did not add those contacts into your adapter. (the adapter list is always empty in your case).

Create a method in your adapter to set the contacts into your adapter.

```
void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    notifiyDataSetChanged();
}

void addContacts(Contact  contact) {
    this.contacts.add(contact);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount()-1);
}
```

Then in your main call setContacts if you wanna add many contacts at once, or use addContacts to add contacts one at a time.